# How can we get new code coverage or per Pull Request with bitbucket

Tags: java, jenkins, code-coverage, cicd, jacoco

I need code coverage of every pull request and the pull request has been generated by bitbucket. so basically I achieved a multibranch that every time a new pull request is generated or modified it automatically triggers the build of that branch can't achieve code coverage of only changed code. we have already tried Jenkins Jacoco plugin, but it gives coverage of the entire code.

I want to achieve that every time a pull request is raised or an update new build has been generated on the multibranch pipeline and generates only changed code coverage and if code coverage for Java is less than the given % then the build should have failed.

Answer (score 0):

assuming sonar, you have the option to specify "-Dsonar.branch.name". so when ever a PR is raised, you can set a custom branch name "PR-NUM-BranchName" and then run sonarqube scan, so that you can see each PR pipeline run report as a separate branch.
sonarqube will anyhow give you the new coverage / changes wrt base branch.